# Is there a way to clear Chrome's cache in a FIFO way?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

[This link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/empty-google-chrome-cache-fix-waiting-for-cache-error/) shows how to clear Chrome's chach in a [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_(computing)) way (clear everything newer than X) but I want to clear it in the other direction, [LRU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used) or [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) (clear everything older than X). *Can this be done? If so, how?*

Comment: I suggest every browser should support this feature!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nirsoft has a little utility that allows you to browse and extract info from Chrome Cache, but apparently it doesn't allow you to delete it.

Google for Nirsoft and ChromeCacheView to find it (sorry but I am allowed only one hyperlink for post due to my newbie status, and I am saving it for the other link ;) )

Here you can find a **[post about how to manipulate the cache](http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2008/09/google-chrome-temporary-files-location.html)**. Best I could find so far.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only possible way is to check cache 'creation date' (file attribute) and delete the older than X. You can write a .bat for that purpose, and execute it with a simple click. (Or write an addon? Never checked Chrome's addon system so far. The whole browser is just so immature imho.)

Comment: I think chrome's cache is a single file. I know it's not stored as individual files.

Comment: Damn this whole site already.. an error comes up every 5min. So. Here is the cache: http://pastebin.ca/1788981 .. IMHO all the cache are in individual files because if I defrag them on Win, it gives me a huge perf boost.